# Socket.io, can't connect on iOS 10

Tags: sockets, ionic-framework, websocket, socket.io, ios10

I use socket.io-client in my Ionic 2 app. Everything work like on charm on Android and iOS <= 9.
On iOS 10 I can't establish a connection. Do I make something wrong or do I miss something?

"socket.io-client": "^1.7.2"

```
this.socket = io.connect(Resources.Constants.API.SERVER_DOMAIN, {
        'transports': ['websocket', 'xhr-polling'],
        'query': 'token=' + myToken
    });

    alert('test:' + this.socket.id); // undefined
   alert('test:' + this.socket.connected); // false
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that last Safari is more picky about CSP than the others.

Adding ws://* wss://* to my connect-src in my Content-Security-Policy solved my issue.

```
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src data: gap://* file://* https://ssl.gstatic.com *; img-src 'self' * data:; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' *; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline' *; connect-src 'self' * ws://* wss://*;">
```